# Connecting datagrid view to database in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Ok so im trying to display everything in my MYSQL database using a datagrid view.  but what i got is not working, can somebody help me with my code

```
    Public Sub dataview()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ""
    Dim bindingSource1 As New BindingSource()
    Try
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM upload", db_con)

    With Me.DataGridView1
        .AutoGenerateColumns = True

        bindingSource1.DataSource = cmd
        .DataSource = bindingSource1

        .AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders
        .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
        .EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter
    End With
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("something went wrong")
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply pass your MySqlCommand to the BindingSource.
You should use a object of type MySqlDataAdapter to get the command and fill a DataSet/DataTable.
That DataTable/DataSet should be used as DataSource for your `bindingSource1`

```
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM upload", db_con)
Dim da = New MySqlDataAdapter (cmd)
Dim dt = New DataTable()
da.Fill(dt)
bindingSource1.DataSource = dt ' here assign the DataTable'

With Me.DataGridView1
    .AutoGenerateColumns = True
    .DataSource = bindingSource1
    .....
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub dataview()
DataGridView1.DataSource = ""
Dim bindingSource1 As New BindingSource()
Try
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM upload", db_con)

With Me.DataGridView1
    .AutoGenerateColumns = True

    bindingSource1.DataSource = cmd
    .DataSource = bindingSource1

    .AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders
    .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
    .EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter
End With
    DataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("something went wrong")
End Try
```

try this one^^